# Android Connecing to MySQL without webservice

Tags: android, mysql

Hello everybody I want to connect my android app to mySQL db without using web services
I searched and found that using JDBC we can do it ...
but the problem is that I can't download the drivers 
could you please help me?
Tank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it adding this `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Here's a tutorial of [JDBC MYSQL CONNECTION TUTORIAL](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jdbc/jdbc-mysql-connection-tutorial/)

Comment: yes, but when i add Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); the app crashes

Comment: i don't know it cant find the class I think

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412135/class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver-newinstance and http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/ and tell me if it was helpful.

Comment: thanks i'll check and answer :)

Comment: If it works don't forget to vote my answer! :) And if you face with more issues let me know.

Comment: sorry but my main problem is downloading the drivers :1.I  can't download them 2.I don't know what i shoukd do after downloading

Comment: This is a tutorial  [link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jdbc/jdbc-mysql-connection-tutorial/) read it... I can't do much more

Comment: @JoanColmenero - Not everyone reads comments. Please put details within the answer itself.