# I am trying to load or u can say register my sql jdbc driver with the use of ServletConfig interface

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I am able to load my mysql jdbc driver from the other ways but when I am trying to register it with the use of servletconfig interface it gives an exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: drive

Though I know the concept of servletconfig interface and trying to do it by following the concept but failed.
Here's my code and other stuff I used.

here is my java class

```
package com.pi.org;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sql.*;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



/**
* Servlet implementation class Validation
*/
public class Validation extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Validation() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse       response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Boolean valid= false;
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String username= request.getParameter("user");
  String  password= request.getParameter("pass");



  try{
      ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
      String driver = config.getInitParameter("driver");
      Class.forName("driver");
     Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdata","root","annie1993"); 

     PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement("select * from emp ");
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

     while(rs.next()){
         if(username.equals(rs.getString(1))&& password.equals(rs.getString(2)))
         {
             valid= true;
     }
     }

     if(valid)
     {
          request.setAttribute("user", username);
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("inbox");
         rd.forward(request, response);

     }

     else{
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index");
         rd.include(request, response);
         out.print("<html><body>either username or password is incorrect<body><html>");


     }

  }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [am trying to load my sql jdbc driver with the use of ServletConfig interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736269/am-trying-to-load-my-sql-jdbc-driver-with-the-use-of-servletconfig-interface)

Answer (score 1):

The error it's because there is no class "driver" the correct sentence is :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

or

```
Class.forName( config.getInitParameter("driver") );
```

But actually this isn't a  correct way to access a database in a servlet see : [Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412135/class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver-newinstance)

Comment: ohh thanks it works , i know the first way  u show Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  to load the driver but am  use this second method Class.forName( config.getInitParameter("driver") ); for what i want to do with the use of servletcofig interface

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Class.forName()` line, but you haven't needed this line at all since 2007, and you therefore don't need the `init` parameter either. Just remove both.